# Can you make WooCommerce shortcodes from template parts?

Tags: templates, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm interested in creating shortcodes that basically fill in template parts of the WooCommerce checkout. For example, in functions.php of my child theme:

```
function shortcode_review_order() {
    //get the template part from woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php
    wc_get_template_part('checkout/review-order');
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_review_order', 'shortcode_review_order' );
```

...and then in my page...

```
<div>[custom_review_order]</div>
```

When I tried this, nothing appeared in my checkout page.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few things wrong in your code...

first, you should add a shortcode using the `init` hook.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_shortcodes' );
function add_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode( 'custom_review_order', 'shortcode_review_order' );
}
```

then you lack the `.php` part of the template. Also it needs the array parameter like below. And you might get more accurate result using `wc_get_template`.

```
function shortcode_review_order(){
    wc_get_template( 'checkout/review-order.php', array( 'checkout' => WC()->checkout() ) );
}
```

To know more on how to correctly use it's template, search for each on the plugin. You'll see how it's being used. And you can get a hint on how you can use it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I actually spent the better part of 3 hours reading up on and experimenting with this and other methods, but none of the examples I found, not even on WooCommerce's own documentation and forums, included the `add_action( 'init', 'add_shortcodes' );` and other stuff you've added. Or maybe I just have rotten luck with searching out code examples. :p

Comment: well. I searched for `add_shortcodes` in the plugin... and saw it was on the `init`. ;) I guess was lucky. haha

Comment: Spoke too soon. On the Checkout page but only in the edit mode, when I include this shortcode in the text editor and save, I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php` and then a stack trace. I must be missing some other "ingredient" but I can't seem to track down what with this vague error message. :(

Comment: what do you mean by edit mode? are you using some frontend editor?

Comment: Just the editor in WordPress. I'm editing the WooCommerce checkout page using the WordPress editor in Text (not visual) mode. I add the `[custom_review_order]` shortcode to it and save it and that's when the error occurs. But the shortcode does render when I load the checkout page in the browser.

Comment: shortcodes will not run on admin side... there must be something wrong but not this code..

Answer (score 1):

I found that wc_get_template echos out the template, instead, for shortcodes returning the template is better. You can use:

`$string = wc_get_template_html( $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path );`

It is "Like wc_get_template, but returns the HTML instead of outputting."

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_template_html.html